# What's happening to my tomato plant leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

Can you help me identify what this is on my tomato plant leaves? It's like *inside* the leaf..you can't feel it by touching the leaf.

If the info helps, the plants are in a container.

[image]

Comment: @EvilElf - its a leaf mining insect of some sort, very common.